# Word for writing over letter or shape

Tags: word-choice, vocabulary

I'm looking for word or phrase which would describe the action of writing over letter or shape in order to practice fine motor skills and writing of that particular letter.
E.g. you get outline of the letter "A" and you write into it to practice writing of it. The outline is used as kind of guide.

I was thinking of using verb "outline the letter", but that would imply to go around the letter and not to write into it.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use the verb 'trace' to talk about the action you describe. The dictionary article mentions a thin piece of transparent paper, ('tracing paper') but schoolchildren are given sheets with printed letters to trace directly using a pencil.

> Trace verb [ T ] (DRAW) ​
>   to copy a drawing or pattern, etc. by
>   drawing over its lines through a thin piece of transparent paper:
>
> Did you draw this picture yourself, or did you trace it?
>   She learned to write her name by tracing out the letters.

[Trace](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/trace)

Comment: I found the verb 'trace', but I thought it meant only to locate sth. (we have traced his phone). Thank you